# order by not working in java

Tags: java, sql

i have written this code in java, there are two sql queries with different oder by columns but bot are showing the same output:
public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{

```
connectDB();
java.sql.Statement st1= con1.createStatement();
java.sql.Statement st2= con2.createStatement();

String query1="select * from entries order by entries.name ;";
System.out.println(query1);

ResultSet rst1=st1.executeQuery(query1);
while(rst1.next()){
    System.out.println(rst1.getString(1)+" "+rst1.getString(2));

}
st1.close();con1.close();

String query2="select * from entries order by entries.number ;";
System.out.println(query2);

ResultSet rst2=st2.executeQuery(query1);
while(rst2.next()){
    System.out.println(rst2.getString(1)+" "+rst2.getString(2));

}
```

the output is as follows:

```
select * from entries order by entries.name ;
Smith 40
Taylor 46
Winland 44
select * from entries order by entries.number ;
Smith 40
Taylor 46
Winland 44
hello
```

my table name is entries and i has only two columns name of type varchar and number of type int

Comment: you are executing query1 second time instead of query 2

Comment: `ResultSet rst2=st2.executeQuery(query1);` it should be `query2` instead of `query1`.

Answer (score 5):

You are executing the same query, a copy-paste error, I think.